# How APIs works and get datas?

Tags: api

First, I'm sorry if it's not the good place to ask this question, but I think it's related with programming.

I'm going to create a website, and this website needs soccer data like scores, players ... etc, I search on the net and I found a lot of APIs that you need to buy for it.

but I'm really confused how this APIs works ? it there are a companies who have employs and watched games and add data manually, or this use other method ? that can I create my own API ? If yes, how can I get the data ?